# C# XML parsing - skipping null tags in some 'items'

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, linq-to-xml

how are we today?

I use this code to read an XML file and place the results in my for each loop afterwards.

```
 var document = XDocument.Load(e.Result);
 if (document.Root == null)
            return;

        var georss = XNamespace.Get("http://www.georss.org/georss");

 var events1 = from ev1 in document.Descendants("channel").Elements("item")

                      let values = ev1.Element(georss + "point").Value.Split(' ')
                      select new       
                      {
                      Latitude = double.Parse(values[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                      Longitude = double.Parse(values[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 
                      Title = (ev1.Element("title").Value),
                                                }; 


          blahblahMethod();

        foreach (var ev1 in events1)
        {
       blah blah do stuff
       }
```

Ok, so there we are, I grab the contents of the "point" and "title" tags which are nested inside each parent "item" tag in the XML file. There are say 10 items in the XML file. The problem is, not all of the 'items' contain the "point" tag. It is completely missing from some items; so there would be just the "title" tag.

When the XML reader reaches a one of these items, it throws a 'NullReferenceException was unhandled'. So its pretty obvious whats happening. Im having trouble working out a way round this. I thought of some 'if' statement that if it gets to a null tag then it will skip that, but cant seem to fit anything in which VS accepts and doesnt throw some error. Any help appreciated. (Beginner here, be gentle please! :-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a loathing for the Query language syntax and prefer to use extension methods directly so I would tweak your from line like this:-

```
from ev1 in document.Descendants("channel").Elements("item")
    .Where(e => e.Element(georss + "point") != null)
```

you could probably add a where clause in the query just after the from to do the same thing.

Comment: the Brummy strikes again... Thanks Anthony, thats cracked it. I had to change "e" to "ev1", I guess that was a mistake? otherwise youve learnt something new ;-) Ive never actually used the Where statement before so that never crossed my mind (Can you tell im fairly new to this!). Thanks again for the lesson in coding!

Comment: Actually one more thing, can you help me understand whats happening here, to me it looks like its filtering the items witout the georss +point tag in, but clearly its doing the opposite! :-D

Comment: @Dan:  Using e was my mistake not because you are using ev1 but because e is already in scope (your code is in an event handler that already uses e as the eventargs parameter).  I could have used:-  pinkElephants => pinkElephants.Element(...) and it would have worked.

Comment: @Dan: " looks like its filtering the items witout the georss +point tag in" umm... no its only including item elements that contain a child point element (the "!= null" is not equal to null).

Comment: Ahh yes I misunderstood the !=null statement. Back to the textbooks for me I think.. Cheers. Dan